# amazon beanstalk, s3 and local files

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a web application in PHP that accepts image uploads from a user interface (sent using some javascript). The PHP application processes the image and saves to disk several different versions and in different formats and resolutions.

Now I'm trying to integrate Amazon S3 into this application.

1) At which point do I actually save the file to S3?

2) Should I only do it at the end to store the final versions and in the meantime save temporary version on the EC2 instance server or should I never save to the EC2 instance?

3) One of my main worries is let's say the user uploads the file but does not press save which is the step that would actually store it to amazon s3, and let's say the load increases before save is pressed, is there a chance the user by the time he/she presses save could end up on a different instance where the local image does not exist?

amazon-web-services amazon-s3 amazon

Answer (score 0):

This probably not the best solution, but at least it worth mentioning: you could mount S3 bucket as a local folder on your server (using [RioFS](https://github.com/skoobe/riofs), for example), and when file is ready to be uploaded to S3 - copy it to that folder, RioFS will automatically upload it to remote S3 bucket.